# EditText error not aligned to the top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to align the error popup to the top of the EditText, but nothing works

This is my code and a editText screenshot

```
 <!-- Body -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"/>
```

[image: Screenshot]

It works great for the text with `gravity=top`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your layout_height to wrap_content ? It seems to be taking up the entire height of your layout

Comment: Yes. That's the idea. I am using layout weight for that reason. The root view is a LinearLayout.